# How to tell git that my current local files are correct?

Tags: git, github

GitHub Desktop is telling me to pull files. If I pull the files from the remote repo I get files that contain many errors and things I don't want.

I am the owner of the repo, and I'm the only person who interacts with it.

Is there a way to set it so that I can say that my current files are absolutely correct, and to ignore anything else that was done?

I want to tell the app that whatever is on the server is incorrect, and just accept my current local files as correct. It shouldn't ask me to pull anything (since those files/changes are not correct).

[image]

Comment: It looks like your local `master` branch is fully committed, so if I understand correctly, you just want to make the remote state exactly your local state for that branch. If that's correct, you can force push master to origin (`git push -f origin master`) and you'll be set. I don't know the GUI equivalent, but that will work from the command line if you run it in your sandbox.

Comment: If you're the only person interacting with the repo, how are they getting out of sync to start with? Rather than forcing it, fix the underlying problem.

Comment: can you attach what `git log` shows you? am i right that firstly you made commits that seems mess for you now and therefore you try to fix it and make another commits that should overwrite what is already pushed?